# Set parent div unscrollable and child div scrollable

Tags: html, css, reactjs, uikit

I'm creating a react application. As following

[image]

The Green bordered div is an uikit off-canvas bar. It's positioned as absolute. There are 3 divs inside of the off-canvas bar. 'B' and 'C' divs' heights can be varied dynamically. What I need to be done is when contents adding to 'B' & 'C' divs, The off-canvas bar(green border div) and 'C' div shouldn't be scrolling. And only 'B' div can scroll.
I can't set heights for 'B' & 'C' dives because their heights can vary. I tried to get 'C' div height using js and it also didn't work. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
This is my code

Green div

```
.secondary-offcanvas .uk-offcanvas-bar {
    padding: 0;
    width: 480px;
    border: 1px solid var(--border-gray);
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

B div

```
.shopping-cart-details {
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**Result** : The parent div stopped scrolling. But the B div still cannot be scrolled. Therefore, the excess part of the B div has been cropped.

Comment: Consider adding a demo of the issue.

Comment: You can add your code of what you've tried so far so everyone can see it.

Comment: So as stuff is added to B and C who 'wins' in terms of being able to grab any remaining space in the green div?

Comment: @AHaworth C should win.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a duplicate, nice :)

you can use `overflow: auto;` for B

but about C, you said it's content can vary, so if content is larger than parent what should it do? Should cut the overflow and make it invisible? :
`overflow:hidden;`

should remain visible?

`overflow:visible ;`

in any if above cases the parent should have `overflow:hidden;`  because you don't want the green border to has scroll bars

if you want B and C to fill the possible gap between them,
Make the parent a flexbox using `display:flex;`

set it's direction to column

`flex-direction: column ;`

and use
`flex-grow:1;`
for flex items (B, C)

this is way b, c will always stretch up to fill their father's height and they'll take equal size of the empty space, you can set different flex-grow for different sizing

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I tried it. The parent div stopped scrolling. But the B div still cannot be scrolled.

Comment: Can you Provide a fiddle or pen of your code? Does B have overflow: auto? , try overflow:scroll; might work (it's problem is that it will have scrollbars regardless of it's content size

Comment: I finally solved the problem. With the help of your answer. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know it, Good luck